# applying rewrite rule at 2 files in the same folder does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following htaccess code to make seo-friendly URLs.
Somehow only the 1st group works corrrectly, independently of the order that they are called in. I imagine that the 1st overwrites the 2nd, but i don't know why. Any ideas would be gladly welcomed!

---

FIRST

```
RewriteRule ^ca/(.+)/$ /ca/empresa.php?idem=$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]\ /ca/empresa\.php\?idem=(.+)\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^ca/empresa\.php$ /ca/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

---

SECOND

```
RewriteRule ^ca/(.+)/$ /ca/servei.php?idse=$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]\ /ca/servei\.php\?idse=(.+)\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^ca/servei\.php$ /ca/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

---

thanks in advance

Comment: You need an extra specification in your SEO URL like `^ca/emprasa/(.+)/$` and `^ca/servei/(.+)/$`

Comment: Your regex is the same for both the first rules in both sets. `^ca/(.+)/$ ` How will the server know which php file you want it to go to? It can't guess.